# Using JavaScript to populate data string in AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I have Page 1 which will request the number of rows from string txtRow and display how many rows of the select box. My select box will have ID selID0, selID1, selID2... and so on depending on how many rows. Then, the user will pick the options in the select boxes. I then will like to check which select box (selID) is not selected by the user using AJAX. I am using javascript to populate the string of the data in Ajax.

```
var kae = "";
 for (i = 0; i< <%=sROW %>; i++){
    var str = '"selID' + i + '":$("#selID' + i + '").val(),';
    kae = kae + str
 }`
 $.ajax({
         url    : url_to,
         type   : 'POST',
         data   :  { "txtRow":$("#txtRow").val(), kae 
         },
```

I then will post to a asp Page 2 to do some checking. If the value in my select box is empty I will return a string

```
response.write "{ ""data"": { ""status"": ""errorInfo"" } }"
```

if all the select boxes, selID0, selID1, selID2... so on depending on how many Rows is selected are all selected. I will return a string

```
response.write "{ ""data"": { ""status"": ""ok "" } }"
```

Back in Page 1 Ajax, I will check the status and display the alert accordingly.

Now the problem arises when passing the selID0, selID1 values to page2. Page 2 does fail to get the values from page 1 if I use a for loop to populate the data. But if I've hardcoded the string like below. I can manage to get the value on page 2. I have checked kae variable and the strings generated are ok but I am not sure why I am unable to pass the values to page 2? Please help, thank you very much.

```
"selID0":$("#selID0").val(),
"selID1":$("#selID1").val(),
```

The complete code for Page 1

```
<%
sRow = Cint(request("txtRow"))
%>

<form name="form2" action="ax_test.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="txtRow" name="txtRow" value="<%=sRow%>" />
<table>
<%  i=0
do while i < Cint(sROW)

    response.write "<tr>"
    response.write "<td>"
    response.write "    <select class='form-control' id='selID" & i & "' name='selID" & i & "'>"
    response.write "        <option value=''>Select</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='a'>a</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='b'>b</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='c'>c</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='d'>d</option>"
    response.write "    </select>"
    response.write "</td>"
    response.write "</tr>"
    i=i+1
loop

%>
</table>


<button type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="save" class="btn btn-default"
    style="width: 90px" onclick="checkselect();">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
function checkselect() {

var url_to  = 'ax_postcheckselect.asp';
var kae = "";

for (i = 0; i< <%=sROW %>; i++){
    var str = '"selID' + i + '":$("#selID' + i + '").val(),';
    kae = kae + str
}

     $.ajax({
         url    : url_to,
         type   : 'POST',
         data   :  { "txtRow":$("#txtRow").val(), kae 
         },
         success    : function(res){

                if(res.data.status == "errorInfo"){
                     return alert('You miss selecting something ');
                }else if(res.data.status == "ok") {
                     alert("Successfull.");
                    location.reload();
                }
         },
         error  : function(error){
             console.log(error);
         }
     });
}
```

The complete code for page 2

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/json"   
Server.ScriptTimeout = 1000000


sRow = request("txtRow")

response.write "{ ""data"": { ""status"": """ & request("selID0") & """ } }"
response.end

bSelect = "Y"
i = 0
do while i < Cint(sRow)
   sID = request("selID" & i )
       if sID = "" then 
            bSelect = "N"
            exit Do     
       end if       
    i = i + 1
loop

if bSelect = "N" then
    response.write "{ ""data"": { ""status"": ""errorInfo"" } }"
    response.end
else
    response.write "{ ""data"": { ""status"": ""ok"" } }"
    response.end 
end if

%>
```

[image: Can't get the value of selID0 in page 2, Please help]

Comment: Are you developing on a workstation version of IIS? Because by default it allows only one request, and your AJAX request might be hanging. You could try increasingthe maximum number of worker processes in the advanced settings of the application pool for this site.

Comment: Hi Rico thanks for your reply, I have switched the maximum number of worker processes to 10 but it is still not working.

Comment: Sorry @Hansheung Cheah, I'm not sure what the pages are supposed to do exactly from your description. But if the main problem is (as you say) that hardcoded objects in your page work, but building them in a FOR loop in JavaScript doesn't, it's propably that your kae variable contains a string, not a JavaScript Object. I would use the browsers debugger to check the contents of your kae variable, and your hard-coded data, and see what's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending the string `$("#selID0").val()`, you have to send it's value.

That is, change:

```
var str = '"selID' + i + '":$("#selID' + i + '").val(),';
```

to:

```
var str = '"selID' + i + '":"' + $("#selID" + i).val() + '",';
```

Check the network tab and see which values are being sent to page2. You should see a field called `kae`, which contains all these selxx values. You will have to change page2 to access these values.

If you haven't already, you should go through [the documentation on $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)